# How to run tests on a single method when the method name `is backticked`()

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, gradle

Running an instrumentation or unit test in the terminal with Gradle is relatively straightforward. Let's take this example class:

```
class MyClass {
   @Test
   fun mySimpleTest() {
      // Test logic here
   }
}
```

To run this single unit test method in the terminal (ignoring the fact that I could use wildcards and such):

```
./gradlew a:b:c:test --tests 'com.sample.package.MyClass.mySimpleTest'
```

But what if you have a Kotlin method that utilizes backticking?

```
class MyClass {
   @Test
   fun `my simple test`() {
      // Test logic here
   }
}
```

I tried replacing the spaces with underscores, removing spaces altogether, with and without backticks, etc and haven't had any success.

**So my question is this: How do you run a single test method in the terminal when the method name utilizes backticks?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Keep the spaces in there:

```
./gradlew a:b:c:test --tests 'com.sample.package.MyClass.my simple test'
```

The JVM *allows* method names with spaces in them. It's just that the Java language doesn't. Kotlin doesn't need to, and doesn't actually change the name of the methods to something else (unless you ask it to with `@JvmName` of course).

Comment: If you only have one test class named `MyClass`, then you can drop the fully-qualified class name. Also, the pattern matching uses globbing, so you could also use `"MyClass.my*"`, which is often useful. Also worth linking to the docs for even more examples: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html

Comment: I could have sworn I tried with spaces, but I guess not. Great answer, and great follow up. Thank you both!